# 404 not found for nesting routes in react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my app, I have the routes

- /auth/login
- /auth/register

And the common parts in page are placed in `Auth.jsx`, use Router to `/auth/login` and `/auth/regster`

But `/auth/login/xxx` will also match `/auth/login`

The only solution to fix is to add `exact`, `Switch` and `Error Route` everywhere

**Is any other solutions for this avoiding writing too many `Error Route`s?**

Codes Following...

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Error from './Error'
import Home from './Home/Home'
import Auth from './Auth/Auth'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/auth" component={Auth}/>
        <Route component={Error}/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

Auth.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'

export default class Auth extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Auth works</div>
        <div>
          <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/login`}>LOGIN</Link>
          <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/register`}>REGISTER</Link>
        </div>
        <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.url}/login`} component={Login}/>
        <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.url}/register`} component={Register}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use a `Redirect` component

Comment: Do I need to use Redirect in every nested route?

Comment: You can use one `Redirect` component that is called when no other paths match. You can call that from your `App.js` file

Comment: But is there a way not modifying the url?

Comment: Thanks all! I've found a brilliant answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/47213581/5497906